# Excel macro to print sheet based on range values

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I'm having some difficult to find the right code for the following goal:

I have a sheet with a macro that when I change a value in the cell E5, automatically fill certain fields in *sheet1*, searches and return values from a table on other sheet - *sheetTable*). So after changing cell E5, *sheet1* is basically ready to print.

My goal is to select a range of values in a column on *sheetTable* and assign each one of them to Cell E5 on *sheet1*, and print each one.

So lets say I select 3 cells with values: 45, 50 and 66. When I run the macro it will assign 45 to cell E5 and print *sheet1*, then it will assign 50 to cell E5 and print *sheet1* and finally will assign 66 to cell E5 and print *sheet1*.

Also, I need to print each ones in PDF and the resulting PDF filename should be the value of E5 cell [basically something like range(e5).value.pdf].

Comment: Didn't got no answer on the other post. And explained better on this one

Comment: Why couldn't you just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46972036/edit) your previous question?  (And that other question **did** have an answer, with someone **still** actively trying to assist you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub printSelectedCells()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Cell As Range

    Path = "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\" 'Change to suite.
    'Alternatively you let user select folder by using Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    For Each Cell In Selection
        Sheet1.Range("E5").Value2 = Cell.Value2
        Sheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            Path & Sheet1.Range("E5").Value2 & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
            True
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: this one returns run-time error '424' on Sheet1.Range("E5").Value2 = Cell.Value2. How to integrate the 2 Sub's?

Comment: Allright. It's good now. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let's deal with one problem at a time. Does the following fill in cell E5 and print each sheet sequentially?

```
Sub Fill_Print()
    Dim Rng As Range, r As Range
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, shTable As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shTable = Sheets("sheetTable")
    Set Rng = Selection

    For Each r In Rng
        sh1.Range("E5").Value = r.Value
        sh1.PrintOut
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: yep this one works great!

Comment: Ok great. Have you got a filepath for where you want to save the PDF files?